# How comparate attributes of multiple fields with array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to comparator all attribute of the inputs with array is coming with those attributes name are in lowercases in DOM those are not lowercases

this is my code

```
$(":input").each(function() {
  $(this).attr('name').toLowerCase()
  console.log($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

this is the array to comparate with

> MISSFIELD:["email","taglines","lastname"];

inputs attribute is like

> Email,TagLines,LastName

Answer (score 3):

The issue is because `this` in your handler function is an Element object, not a jQuery object, and hence has no `attr()` method.

To fix this create a jQuery object from `this`:

```
$(":input").each(function () {
  console.log($(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Taking this a step further, you can set all the `name` attributes on the controls to lowercase by providing a function to `prop()` which returns the new name value to use:

```
$(':input').prop('name', function(i, name) {
  return name.toLowerCase();
});
```

Comment: This is working but my problem is I try comparator a array I have with a list of attributes  names  all those coming in lowercases, the prop() is working but it changing the attribute I just want to make a comparation but not changes those attribute on my DOM how I can do it ?

Comment: In that case you simply need to loop through the elements and compare to the array, not set their name attributes as your title states. Could you edit the question to include an example of the array

Comment: please can you put here a example of that coding ?

Comment: I would if I could - hence why I asked to see a sample of your array format.

Comment: this is my array MISSFIELD:["email","taglines","lastname"];

Answer (score 0):

well I solve this issue with this code, I don't know it is the better way but is working for mi.

```
 $(":input").each(function () {
                    console.log($(this).attr('name'));
                    if(MISSFIELD.indexOf($(this).prop('name').toLowerCase()) > -1) {
                        $(this).css({'border-left':'4px solid #990000','border-right':'4px solid #990000'});
                    }
                });
```